# Which launch system, New Glenn or Falcon 9, has received more government subsidies?

Tags: spacex, blue-origin

Which launch system, Blue Origin's New Glenn or SpaceX's Falcon 9, has received more government subsidies?  By how much?

Consider a subsidy to be a direct payment, a grant, a procurement where there was only one supplier (a monopoly), or a procurement of an item where the government was the only customer for the product (a monopsony).  Feel free to provide your own, different definition.

Comment: What do you consider a "government subsidy" If your refering to the early cots then Blue Origin did not advance so .... But Blue Origin did get a contract to replace the / supplement the Russian Rockets being used.

Comment: Should we differentiate between subsidies and contracts? 'cause most (all?) of government money for SpaceX was actually in contracts to perform services, not as a subsidy to perform R&D.

Comment: I'm open to definition but I would include direct payments, purchase of services (especially non-competes where no other supplier exists), or grants.

Comment: I dont think that exist, Boing and SpaceX ULA(?) have advanced symmetrically. Sorry the does not exist refers to no other supplier exist. Also you would need to exclude the $800 Million Boeing and Lockheed (ULA) gets as a standing annual gift to just be there to accept rfq's.

Answer (score 10):

I don't care to enter the fray of what is a subsidy, etc. but Parabolic Arc recently published [a nice summary](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2017/03/07/nasas-commercial-cargo-crew-spending/) of what has been spent (or contracted for) by NASA on the commercial contracts to date.

(Note: this is incomplete, it includes NASA spending on commercial crew and cargo only. DOD contracts with Blue Origin, for example, are not listed.)

[image]

From this, SpaceX has been paid (or contracted for) 7.24 **b**illion dollars, and Blue Origin has been paid (or contracted for) 25.7 **m**illion dollars.

Comment: I think you will find this to be a FAR MORE AUTHORITATIVE and explanatory source https://www.nasa.gov/content/commercial-crew-program-the-essentials/ why would you omitt that as the phases were completed some participants were NOT selected for continuation.  AS the OP questioned BO vs SpaceX is either vague and ambiguous allowing for the ACCUMULATED totals to SpaceX that Blue Origin was NOT invited to participate in OR it is not ambiguous and compares the TOTAL for the phases they did compete in.

Comment: In addition, Looking at the Parabolic Arc web site http://www.parabolicarc.com/ I was unable to find the information you attributed to them. Can you please supply the link to that Information?

Comment: The link is in my answer already.  I didn't "omitt" (sic) anything. Please post your own, MORE AUTHORITATIVE answer if you feel mine is sub-par.

Comment: Considering there is NO information on "Blue Origin's New Glenn" that is going to be a tad bit hard to do. And I for one would prefer NOT to contribute to an question than can not be answered with an answer that does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Blue Origin's New Glenn announcement http://www.space.com/34034-blue-origin-new-glenn-rocket-for-satellites-people.html

Comment: I would also point out your information says quite clearly "launch abort system" which you then use to compare to the OP's question comparing ROCKETS. You are comparing an Apple tree to a golf cart as in they are not related. So you comparing \$7.24 Billion to $25.7 is 100% invalid.

Comment: I said in my answer that it was incomplete since it only contained information about NASA funding to the commercial contractors.  If you have additional information about funding provided to Blue Origin (for example, in the ULA/DOD contract to develop a new engine), please share that by posting an answer. Continuing to post comments pointing out that my answer is incomplete seems a bit redundant.

Comment: I said your comparison is invalid vs the OP's question. Why do you think it is valid to compare a launch abort system, in case you do not know what that is, it is a system on the capsule that lifts the capsule clear of an impending catastrophe, to a first and second stage rocket?

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation of what a launch abort system is.  If you do not like my answer, the expected response would be to down vote it, not to post an extended rant in the comments.  I suggest you do that and move on.